# Excel User Input, read the database, and put value to listbox

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub SearchGuess_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WP").Range("WP")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=TextBox1.Value, _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlContains, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            rowNumber = Rng.Row
        Else
            rowNumber = 0
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WP").Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value
End Sub
```

I would like the user to search or guess a string that is in the Excel database,
whenever they type a string that is containing the data from database,
then it would print onto the listbox and then they can select, continue and edit.

Any idea how to do this, above is the only thing I can do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im about to post a screenshot, but I need 10 reps, too hard to explain it by words

Answer (score 1):

Use a range.find loop to populate an array, then set the .List property of your listbox to the array that you created:

```
Private Sub SearchGuess_Click()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrList() As Variant
    Dim arrIndex As Long
    Dim strFirst As String

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WP").Range("WP")
        Set rngFound = .Find(Me.TextBox1.Text, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrList(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "*"))
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                arrIndex = arrIndex + 1
                arrList(arrIndex) = .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "A").Text
                Set rngFound = .Find(Me.TextBox1.Text, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
            Me.ListBox1.List = arrList
        Else
            MsgBox "No matches found for [" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "].", , "No Results"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```